# codeigniter: pasar variable de una vista a otra

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Resulta que estoy utilizando *Codeigniter* y quiero realizar lo siguiente:

En el modelo realizo una consulta la cual cargo en un `array` en el `index` de mi controlador, que posteriormente lo muestro en una tabla a través de un `foreach` en la vista...

Mi pregunta es: Una de las cosas que obtengo de la consulta es el código el cual quiero que este como un `link` a otra vista, y utilizarla como parámetro para otra consulta, me podrían ayudar por favor soy novato en esto.

```
<?php
  foreach($array as $fila)
  {
?>
<tr>
  <td><a href=""><?=$fila->codigo?></a></td>
  <td><?=$fila->nombre?></td>
  <td><?=$fila->fecha?></td>
  <td>
</tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Bueno en el modelo tengo una consulta simple con un `select`, y en el `index` del controlador, comente que cargaba el resultado de esa consulta en un `array` que luego mando ala vista y la muestro mas o menos como el código que adjunte, y en la fila de código puse una etiqueta a `href` y que ese código poder mandarlo a otra a otra vista.

Comment: Considera añadir un poco del código que llevas y explicarte mejor para poder ayudarte ya que con la descripción que haz hecho a mi personalmente no me queda muy claro que es lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 0):

Desde la vista , donde `tu_vista` debe ser la función de tu controlador.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('tu_controlador/tu_vista/'.$fila->codigo);?>"> Texto </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al llamar a la vista en el controlador, le pasas la variable en formato array en el segundo parámetro de la función load:

Controlador:

```
function pagina() {
    $color = 'azul';
    $this->load->view("vista_view", array('color' => $color));
}
```

Vista:

```
<p>Color: <?php echo $color; ?></p>
```

Se muestra:

```
Color: azul
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si termino de entender tu pregunta, pero deberías poner la variable en el href del link.

Y `$fila->codigo` debería tener algo de la forma "`/controller/vista/codigo`".

```
<?php
  foreach($array as $fila)
  {
?>
<tr>
  <td><a href="<?=$fila->codigo?>"><?=$fila->codigo?></a></td>
  <td><?=$fila->nombre?></td>
  <td><?=$fila->fecha?></td>
  <td>
</tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```